# Excel pick element from list in cell

Tags: excel, cell

I want to select an element from a list in a cell.

This does not work:

```
A1 {10;20}
B1 =index(A1;2) => #VERW! (Dutch)
```

This works:

```
=INDEX({10;20};2) => 20
```

How can I select a value from the list in `A1` with a function in another cell?

Comment: [Maybe use FILTERXML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61837696/excel-extract-substrings-from-string-using-filterxml/61837697#61837697).

Comment: a single cell cannot hold an array of values.  To Excel the `{10;20}` in A1 is just a string.

Comment: Assuming dynamic arrays are supported, A1 `={10,20}` and B1 `=INDEX(A1#,2)` would work close to what you are expecting but the array would spill into A2.